# How to get element's property value in real time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, element

I'm totally new on this. And for now ReactJs is deep forest for me. Documentation is very complicate. Hard to understand what function and where to write, even declare variables. I want to get the elements attributes values in real time. How to do that?

```
class Comment extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.chatRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            buttonIsHidden: 'none',
            maskIsHidden: true,
            size: 0
        }
     }   

     componentDidMount() {
        const size = this.chatRef.current.clientHeight;
        this.setState({size: size});
     }

     render() {
        console.log(this.state.size);
        return(
```

I always get same value 50px... But I know that textarea changes size between 50-150px.

Comment: Have you tried using componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount?

Comment: i get error : Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Yeah put an if statement around the body of the function checking if this.state.size is equal to the const you are setting it to and that will fix that

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    size: ""
  };
  getSize = () => {
    console.log(this.refs.hello.offsetWidth);
    this.setState({ size: this.refs.hello.offsetWidth });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.getSize()}> Get Size </button>
        <textarea onMouseMove={() => this.getSize()} ref={"hello"} />
        {this.state.size}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit pw7njz99qx]

You do not want to use `componentDidMount()` because that only happens after the first render.

The getSize function uses refs to reference the `textarea`, and we add `onMouseMove` handler to the `textarea` which will give you the realtime value of the size.

> The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout
>   width of an element. Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a
>   measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal
>   padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and
>   the element CSS width. If the element is hidden (for example, by
>   style.display on the element or one of its ancestors to "none"), then
>   0 is returned.

Read about [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)